# Proof check - Let $X$ be a separable infinite dimensional Banach space. Then $X$ is not complete with respect to "basis-norm"

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

It'd be nice if someone could point out any potential mistakes in the following:

> Let $X$ be a separable infinite dimensional Banach space. Suppose that $X$ has a Hamel (algebraic) basis $B=\{x_i:i\in I\}$ for an indexing set $I$, with $\|x_i\|=1$ for all $i$. Define a new norm $[\cdot]$ by
>
> $$ [x]=\sum_{i\in I} |\lambda_i|$$
>
> Where $x=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i x_i$. Show that $X$ is not complete with this new norm.

Since $X$ is infinite dimensional and complete, then $I$ must be uncountable. So we can find a linearly independent subset $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ of $B$.

Let $x^n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}x_k$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^2$ is convergent $x^n$ is Cauchy in $[\cdot]$ norm.

It's easy to see that $\|x\|\le [x]$ for all $x\in X \;\;(*)$,

so then $x^n$ is Cauchy in $\|\cdot\|$ norm. Therefore, $x^n\to x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}x_k\in X$
in $\|\cdot\|$ norm.

This means that we can find $\{y_1,\cdots,y_m\}\subset B$ such that $x=\sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k y_k$ ($\alpha_i\neq 0$ for all $i$) such that there exists some $j$ with $y_j\notin \{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$

Due to $(*)$, if $x^n$ converged to some $y$ in $[\cdot]$ norm, then $x^n\to y$ in $\|\cdot\|$ norm, and so $x=y$.

But $[x^n-x]\ge |\alpha_j|>0$ so it's impossible to have $x^n\to x$ in $[\cdot]$ norm. Hence $x^n$ is not convergent in $[\cdot]$ norm, and $(X,[\cdot])$ is not complete.

---

I'm also interested in other ways to do the problem; I see that choice of $x^n$ is completely arbitrary - it would have been enough to choose any convergent series instead of $\sum 1/n^2$. Are there  ways to this without giving explicit examples? (or maybe, significantly easier counterexamples)

Also I didn't use separability - why is it needed?

Comment: I think the separability is to let you give a very quick solution.  If both norms were complete then by the open mapping theorem the identity map would be a homeomorphism between them.  But the $\|\cdot\|$ topology is separable and the $[\cdot]$ topology is not ($B$ is an uncountable closed discrete set).

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. Any two distinct element of $B$ is at distance $2$ apart from each other in $[\cdot]$, so any dense subset must contain at least as much elements as $B$ does, which must be uncountable. That makes a lot of sense why separability is put in here; Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anyway, I think your proof is fine too, and shows you that the separability assumption is not needed.